# Rails 4.1 Variants: how to handle the "desktop version" button

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to add a mobile version of my rails 4.1 website.

I'm addind to the menu a button "view desktop version"

How can I handle it?

I think to pass a parameter in the url, for example

```
http://www.example.com/?desktop=1

class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  # Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
  # For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception

  before_action :detect_device_format

  private

    def detect_device_format
      return if params[:desktop] == 1
      case request.user_agent
      when /iPad/i
        request.variant = :tablet
      when /iPhone/i
        request.variant = :phone
      when /Android/i && /mobile/i
        request.variant = :phone
      when /Android/i
        request.variant = :tablet
      when /Windows Phone/i
        request.variant = :phone
      end
    end
end
```

In this way I can't keep setting for every request... how can I fix it?

Comment: put it in a cookie or store it in the session?